# Trouble matching states to capitals

Tags: java, arrays, file

I created two arrays and assigned states to one array and capitals to the other array that I got from a text file.  The text file is formatted like this:

Colorado,Denver,

Wisconsin,Madison,

..........etc

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class StatesAndCapitals {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("capitals.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(is);
        String[] states = new String[50];
        String[] capitals = new String[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
            String currentLine = input.nextLine();
            int a = currentLine.indexOf(",");
            String states1 = currentLine.substring(0, a);
            states[i] = states1;
            int b = currentLine.lastIndexOf(",");
            String capitals1 = currentLine.substring(a+1, b);
            capitals[i] = capitals1;
        }//end for loop
    }
}
```

The point of my program is to ask "What is the capital of (blank)?"

Then I need to tell the person if they are correct or not. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to check if, for example, Madison is the capital of Wisconsin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Much easier to use `split` on the input string instead of all the indexOf and substring work

Comment: So what is not working?  You apparently haven't yet made any effort to look up the state name in your array of states.

Comment: Steps To Solve :
1. You need to display the question ""what is the capital of " + states[i].
2. You need to get input from the user for thier answer (maybe a Scanner)
3.  You need to compare their answer to capitals[i]

Comment: sorry i wasn't more specific.  thats the problem I have.  I dont know how to link states and capitals together so I can't tell them if they are right or not

Comment: Well, assuming you have `i + 1` number of states and capitols, then an index `i` should refer to the i-th state and the i-th capitol in each array, respectively. Use the same index to match state and capitol, beginning from `0` and all the way to `i`.

Comment: Or one could stash both in a Map as they're read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("capitals.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String[] stateAndCapital = scanner.next().split(",");
            System.out.println(String.format("What is the capital of %s?",
                    stateAndCapital[0]));
            System.out.println(userInput.next().equals(stateAndCapital[1]));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

output:

```
What is the capital of Colorado?
dunno
false
What is the capital of Wisconsin?
Madison
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
public boolean isCapitalOfState(String capital, String state) {
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        if (state[i].equals(state) && capitals[i].equals(capital)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It loops through the array of `state`s and once it has found the match, it will check if the `capital` matches, if so `return true`. If it has not found anything it will by default `return false`.

Note though that there are a lot of easier ways to achieve your behaviour. Generally, `List`s are superior to `Array`s.

**EDIT:** I see your question asks for a bit more, we here cannot give you a full program to do it. However do keep in mind that when you've already obtained an index in `state`, that you can check the result way easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

These are setup like parallel arrays correct? Meaning for example states[0] = colorado, and capitals[0] = denver, it looks this way but if it is indeed setup like this use the index of the state as the index for the capital and compare the input against that.
For example,

```
System.out.println("What is the capital of " + states[i]);
capital = input.nextLine();
if(capital.equals(capitals[i]){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```